# How can I add an id_token to the response_type in OWIN when using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

How can I add an id_token to the response_type in OWIN when using MVC?

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    ClientId = "my client id",
                    ClientSecret = "my secret",
                    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnApplyRedirect = context =>
                        {
                            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                            {
                                { "response_type", "code id_token" },
                                { "openid.realm", "my realm IP" }
                            };
                            var redirectUri = WebUtilities.AddQueryString(context.RedirectUri, dictionary);
                            context.Response.Redirect(redirectUri);
                        }
                    }

                });
```

This code returns an error since there can only be one response_type parameter included in the redirectUri.

How can I add the id_token to the response_type parameter?

FYI.. this is required when migrating to OAuth2 in order to reference the user's old Google id since they've switched to a GUID.

Comment: For future reference, there are specific tags for ASP.NET MVC - the tag you originally used is intended for questions regarding the pattern, not a specific implementation.

Comment: Tieson - I reviewed GoogleAuthenticationHandler.ApplyResponseChallengeAsync which calls OnApplyRedirect. I don't see where 'response_type' is set, but I do see 'openid.realm'. I suspect you will have to rebuild the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be done...

```
GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "my_clientid",
                ClientSecret = "my_secret",
                Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnApplyRedirect = context =>
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                        {
                            { "openid.realm", "my realm URL"},
                        };
                        string redirect = context.RedirectUri.Replace("response_type=code", "response_type=code id_token");
                        var redirectUri = WebUtilities.AddQueryString(redirect, dictionary);
                        context.Response.Redirect(redirectUri);
                    },                    

                },
            };
```